# How should I use route and view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have started to learn laravel. I want to display `test` view on link click from `welcome` view, so I used

route method,

```
Route::get('AGE/',function() {
    return view('test');
});
```

In my `welcome` view I used

```
<a href="http://localhost:8000/AGE">Test</a>
```

to display `test`view.

I just want to know the way that I have used to perform required task is a good practice or not. If not please suggest me how to do so? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sometimes starting from the documentation is better than stackoverflow, for example you might find something interesting in the laravel doc for view (at least for future issues)  https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views Feel free to explore the whole documentation and you will find out what I am trying to convey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you can write an function in Route for **testing only**.

In a real project, you must use an Controller in route to working. It's like

```
Route::get('age',['as' => 'getAge','uses' => 'HomeController@getAge']);
```

In HomeController

```
public function getAge(){
     return view('welcome');
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `URL::to()` which adds `http://localhost:8000/` like this:

```
<a href="{{URL::to('/AGE')}}">Test</a>
```

Make a controller using artisan command,

```
php artisan make:controller TestController
```

Now make a function

```
public function getTest(){
    return view('test');
}
```

And, define route like:

```
 Route::get('/AGE', 'TestController@getTest');
```

In this way you can do your task.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to hardcode the link. You could use [helper methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#urls)

```
<a href="{{ url('/AGE') }}">Test</a>
```

or provide an alias to your route

```
Route::get('AGE', function() {
    return view('test');
})->name('test');
```

and call the named route as

```
<a href="{{ route('test') }}">Test</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Include your domain url will make your site not dynamic. Instead use [url()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-url). Also the `{{ }}` is how to [display data in blade file](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data)

```
<a href="{{ url('AGE') }}">Test</a>
```

Take note that always use small case for url. i.e /age instead of /AGE